# Jquery Add Line Breaks On html()

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

```
success: function(usernames){
           //alert(usernames); ["adam","adam","adam","adam","adam"]
           //alert(usernames.length); 36
           var participants_list= eval(usernames); //adam,adam,adam,adam,adam
           //alert(participants_list.length);5
           var username= '';
           for(var i=0; i<participants_list.length; i++){

               username += participants_list[i] + "\n";

           }
           $("#usernames").html(username);
       }
    });
```

I am trying to add line breaks to #usernames so that each adam will be displayed on a new line but I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

```
<td><div id="usernames">cindy</div></td>
```

Comment: You can either use `<br/>` **generally a bad practice** or modify the HTML structure in a way that makes sense: `<ul id="usernames"><li>cindy</li><li>adam</li></ul>` You can then use CSS to change how this would be displayed.

Comment: Would it be a better way if I can somehow create a new tr/td with each "adam"? You got some pointers?

Comment: You should generally be avoiding tables like Jersey Shore.

Comment: That would depend on the purpose of this display. Generally speaking, tables should be used only for tabular data. So yes, it could be appropriate to generate a new row for each User. If you're just listing the users, it is better to use a list. `<ul> or <ol>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to wrap each user name in a block level element to force them onto their own separate lines. For instance,

```
username = "<p>" + participants_list[i] + "</p>";
```

Perhaps even better in your case would be

```
username = "<tr class='user'><td>" + participants_list[i] + "</td></tr>";

$("your table id or class").append(username);
```

Comment: Would it be a better way if I can somehow create a new tr/td with each "adam"? You got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not to critisize you, but please allow me to improve your code a little:
 - try avoiding the use of eval. eval is evil! In stead you should always try to return valid data by using jsonencode or serialize on the server side.
 - in stead of building that for loop, it would be much easier to use the .each() function in jQuery

Your code would become something like this:

```
jQuery.each(usernames, function(index, value) {
  $('#usernames').append($('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>'));   
});
```

I set up a small example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/YsrWs/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I am very glad to have someone to help me improve my coding skills. Thanks!

Comment: jep, if you tell the ajax call that it should expect json as dataType your eval should be not required.